# app starts ignores user interaction events when i call animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios5, core-animation, objective-c-blocks

I have a button that glows in my app (subclass of UIButton). To animate the glowing i use the following method

```
- (void)glow
{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f 
                          delay:0.0f 
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut 
                     animations:^(void){

                         if (glowingImageView_.alpha != 1.0f) {
                             [glowingImageView_ setAlpha:1.0f];
                         }
                         else {
                             [glowingImageView_ setAlpha:0.3f];
                         }

                     } 
                     completion:^(BOOL finnished){

                         if (on_) {
                             [self glow];
                         }

                     }];

}
```

It works fine running on iOS 5, but in iOS 4.3 my app stops handling any user interaction. Any one have any idea what might be causing this?

Thanks

Comment: Don't support iOS 4.3? There are many api changes throughout the versions of iOS, its not surprising that certain things are different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) Docs:

During an animation, user interactions are temporarily disabled for the views being animated. **(Prior to iOS 5, user interactions are disabled for the entire application.)** If you want users to be able to interact with the views, include the `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` constant in the options parameter.

So in iOS 4.3,  user interactions were disabled. Thats your problem.

Comment: This is a *major* change in iOS behavior. This answer does an excellent job of calling out this fact clearly.