# touchesMoved called without touchesBegan

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, touchesbegan, touchesmoved

I have many custom UIViews within a container, which I animate after the user moves them. To track their movement, I get the current position with `touchesBegan:`, and update the position with `touchesMoved:`.

Occasionally, particularly if I've moved a view very recently (and it may still be animating back to its original position), if I begin dragging another view the `touchesBegan:` selector will not be called, but `touchesMoved:` and `touchesEnded:` will be. How can `touchesMoved:` and `touchesEnded:` be called without `touchesBegan:` first being called on the view?

Answer (score 2):

I found a similar issue with my app. When I animate a view out of the way of another view, if I quickly touch the first view and start swiping, the touchesBegan event never occurs but I start getting touchesMoved once the first view has gone.

According to this answer, [app starts ignores user interaction events when i call animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433483/app-starts-ignores-user-interaction-events-when-i-call-animatewithdurationdelay), user interaction events get ignored while animating, which I think is consistent with what we're both seeing. Try using the `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` option or `userInteractionEnabled` property; that should allow events through as you require.

Answer (score 1):

Probably worth re-reading the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html). I'm not sure if `touchesBegan` is *guaranteed* to be called.

I'm guessing you're logging the `touchesBegan` etc events. Perhaps the correct events are firing but the log messages are appearing "out of order"?

Comment: I thought I remembered reading that touchesBegan was guaranteed to be called, but I guess I misremembered. I am logging at each of the touch events, and when the error occurs it never logs touchesBegan. If I can't find a better solution, I'll just keep a flag to tell when touchesBegan was called, and only perform the touchesMoved and touchesEnded action when that flag is set.